# Applying custom model manager to Django Admin (for proxy models)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two proxy models that inherit from a base. These proxy models each have their own validation rules.

```
class FooManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        if "bar" in kwargs:
            raise ValidationError("Foo object should not have bar field")
        return super(FooManager, self).create(**kwargs)

class BarManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, **kwargs):
        if "foo" in kwargs:
            raise ValidationError("Bar object should not have foo field")
        return super(BarManager, self).create(**kwargs)

class Base(models.Model):
    foo = CharField()
    bar = CharField()

class Foo(Base):
    objects = FooManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class Bar(Base):
    objects = BarManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

So in the shell, everything works as intended:

```
# These are created
Foo.objects.create(foo="foo")
Bar.objects.create(bar="bar")

# These will raise the correct ValidationErrors
Foo.objects.create(bar="bar")
Bar.objects.create(foo="foo")
```

But if I try to create an object via Django's Admin, the validation no longer works. I can create a `Foo` object with a `bar` field and a `Bar` object with a `foo` field.

Is it possible to apply my Custom Managers to Django's Model Admin?

Edit: I am using [Single Table Inheritance](https://schinckel.net/2013/07/28/django-single-table-inheritance-on-the-cheap./)

Edit 2: I could just filter out `foo` and `bar` in the ModelAdmin's `fields` for my specific example but what if I had actual validation (e.g. `foo` field must start with "foo-") that I wanted to pass on to the Admin?

Answer (score 0):

With a proxy model you generally have a single field that determines type, not two:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        FOO = "foo", "foo"
        BAR = "bar", "bar"
    type = CharField(choices=Types.choices)

    def save(self, ..):
        if not self.pk:
            self.type = self.base_type
        super().save(..)


class Foo(Base):
    base_type = Foo.Types.FOO
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class Bar(Base):
    base_type = Bar.Types.BAR
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

(You could update the managers as well to set type correctly). If you need different fields per proxy model, you add those as tables with a OneToOne-key to the subtype in question.

You could have validation-methods on each subtype (or manager).

I currently have a setup where I only have the Base in the admin.You could add both Foo and Bar to the admin and not add Base, it all depends on why you are using proxy models.